# Fill a large matrix with ones and zeros - six nested loops

Tags: c++, optimization, matrix

The following code is to fill a matrix with ones and zeros for a problem in operations research - I will spare you the details. The issue that I have is that there are 6 nested loops, and even though the code compiles perfectly, the print statements at the end are not executed (I don't get any error messages whatsoever though). Could anyone please tell me why this happens, and, if the 6 nested loops are too much to process in this way, whether there would be an other way to implement the same. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<int> > A(480, std::vector<int>(100000));
    int index = 1;
    int N;
    int N2;
    int N3;
    int N4;
    int N5;
    vector<int> indices1;
    vector<int> indices2;
    vector<int> indices3;
    vector<int> indices4;
    vector<int> indices5;                   

    for (int s1 = 0; s1 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s1++)
    {
        if (s1 + 24 + 24 - 1 <= 480 - 24 + 1)
        {
            for (int s2 = s1 + 24 + 24 - 1; s2 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s2++)
            {
                if (s2 + 24 + 24 - 1 <= 480 - 24 + 1)
                {
                    for (int s3 = s2 + 24 + 24 - 1; s3 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s3++)
                    {
                        if (s3 + 24 + 24 - 1 <= 480 - 24 + 1)
                        {
                            for (int s4 = s3 + 24 + 24 - 1; s4 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s4++)
                            {
                                if (s4 + 24 + 24 - 1 <= 480 - 24 + 1)
                                {
                                    for (int s5 = s4 + 24 + 24 - 1; s5 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s5++)
                                    {

                                        // generate print5
                                        for (int pos = 0; pos <= 10; pos++)
                                        {

                                            indices1.push_back(s1 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s1 + 13 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s2 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s2 + 13 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s3 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s3 + 13 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s4 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s4 + 13 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s5 + pos);
                                            indices1.push_back(s5 + 13 + pos);

                                        }
                                        std::sort(indices1.begin(), indices1.end());

                                        // now loop over print5, N is number of elements in indices1
                                        N = 11 * 10;
                                        for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < N; ind1++)
                                        {
                                            A [ indices1[ind1] ][index] = 1;

                                        }

                                        index = index + 1;

                                    }
                                }

                                //else statement
                                //generate print4
                                for (int pos = 0; pos <= 10; pos++)
                                {

                                    indices2.push_back(s1 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s1 + 13 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s2 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s2 + 13 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s3 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s3 + 13 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s4 + pos);
                                    indices2.push_back(s4 + 13 + pos);

                                }
                                std::sort(indices2.begin(), indices2.end());

                                //now loop over print4
                                N2 = 11 * 8;
                                for (int ind2 = 0; ind2 < N2; ind2++)
                                {
                                    A [ indices2[ind2] ][index] = 1;

                                }
                                index = index + 1;

                            }

                        }

                        //else statement
                        // generate print3
                        for (int pos = 0; pos <= 10; pos++)
                        {

                            indices3.push_back(s1 + pos);
                            indices3.push_back(s1 + 13 + pos);
                            indices3.push_back(s2 + pos);
                            indices3.push_back(s2 + 13 + pos);
                            indices3.push_back(s3 + pos);
                            indices3.push_back(s3 + 13 + pos);

                        }
                        std::sort(indices3.begin(), indices3.end());

                        //now loop over print3
                        N3 = 11 * 6;
                        for (int ind3 = 0; ind3 < N3; ind3++)
                        {
                            A [ indices3[ind3] ][index] = 1;

                        }
                        index = index + 1;
                    }

                }
                //else statement
                //generate print2
                for (int pos = 0; pos <= 10; pos++)
                {

                    indices4.push_back(s1 + pos);
                    indices4.push_back(s1 + 13 + pos);
                    indices4.push_back(s2 + pos);
                    indices4.push_back(s2 + 13 + pos);

                }
                std::sort(indices4.begin(), indices4.end());

                //now loop over print2
                N4 = 11 * 4;
                for (int ind4 = 0; ind4 < N4; ind4++)
                {
                    A [ indices4[ind4] ][index] = 1;

                }
                index = index + 1;
            }
        }
        //last else statement
        //generate print1
        for (int pos = 0; pos <= 10; pos++)
        {

            indices5.push_back(s1 + pos);
            indices5.push_back(s1 + 13 + pos);

        }
        std::sort(indices5.begin(), indices5.end());

        //now loop over print1
        N5 = 11 * 2;
        for (int ind5 = 0; ind5 < N5; ind5++)
        {
            A [ indices5[ind5] ][index] = 1;

        }
        index = index + 1;

    }


    // now print elements - I only print till element 50 here, since I dont actually know how many
    // columns I need, therefore I initialized that to a big number (since I will need a lot)
    for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a sparse representation.

Comment: @djechlin Yes, but that's easier said than done in this case. I considered a lot of alternatives, but I could not find a proper way to do it. Would you know how?

Comment: This is a shift scheduling problem, the matrix A should have a 1 when a shift is working, and a 0 else. There are in total 480 periods, the number of different options is however not known and very big.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if` statement?  they appear to be completely redundant.

Comment: Probably recursion. You shouldn't be having to duplicate the *same* *exact* thing so many times.

Comment: Imagine this way: Your boss says "okay but can this work in 24 dimension? On second thought let me just input the number of dimensions when the program starts." Do you a) code that, b) tell your boss it's impossible, or c) quit your job because you can't do it? A program can definitely do it, so (a).

Comment: @Anycorn They are to check whether someone works 5 shifts, or less. I think they are necessary for it to work.

Comment: You could do this with recursion or a simple while(true) loop. s1, s2, ..., by their names alone, should jump out to you as elements in an array. so you have int s[] instead of a bunch of s's; increment then when appropriate.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks a lot for at least taking me seriously :). Could you help me on my way? I can understand that you don't want to do all the coding but could you please give me an example?

Comment: Also Anycorn is right. Your design is clearly wrong in the first place. Two loops to fill a matrix max. Find a better data structure and algorithm from which to do this calculation. Possibly just structured programming logic with no loops, possibly a map, but there is a simpler way.

Comment: @djechlin I understand that the design is flawed. It is just that I cannot find a better way to implement it (and neither could the people that I asked). But if you could think of a different way I'd greatly appreciate that. I just think it's not that easy.

Comment: @dreamer You'd be better served by cleaning up code first.  If your if statements are only guarding against executing a for loop - they are uneccessary - the loop will not execute if initial condition is false.  There is such deep nesting in your code that it is impossible to tell where the scope begins/ends.

Comment: @Anycorn Ok, if you're convinced that I can delete the if statements, then I will. But then still, I think it would not work.

Comment: @Anycorn I tried to rerun the program without all the if statements, again it compiles but no reaction. I think that recursion like djechlin proposed or an other design like that might be the only option - but I'm simply not sure where to start.

Comment: So you are trying to make software to allow your boss to map out 5 shifts across 20 days? Sounds like a simple grid of 24 hours by 20 days, with storage for 5 shifts. Have you thought about how your boss is going to start/stop/edit when a shift starts or stops (ie, the GUI)? That might give you insight into how much of the data you actually need in a discrete storage element.

Comment: In fact, you could just create a 2 dimensional grid and use bitmap masking to determine if a shift works that hour. Do it all in 2^5 bits storage per grid square.

Comment: @StarPilot It's actually for a research project, not my boss ;). Maybe I should explain it in more detail: I want shifts that last for a total of 24 periods, and after that, there should be a break of AT LEAST 24 periods. The total amount of periods is 480. Now I want all the different combinations in a matrix, where a 1 indicates that a certain shift is working in a certain period, a 0 else. Also, a shift can start working in any period, so it could also be possible for instance that it starts in period 5 and then works for 12 hours and then quits (so that it does only 1 12 hour shift).

Comment: @StarPilot That sounds interesting, but to be honest I am not at all familiar with the terms that you're using (could you give me an example?). Also, I should probably mention that I really need this specific representation of the A matrix, as it will be processed in a different program afterwards.

Comment: @StarPilot No they cannot. A shift is really exactly 24 periods and then 24 periods break (at least). And I basically need all those shift types.

Comment: @StarPilot Ah sorry, maybe that is not what you meant. One shift can be busy when also another one is busy (if that's what you meant).

Comment: @djechlin I posted a new implementation as an answer. Could you please look at it? I would higly appreciate it if you could.

Comment: @Anycorn I posted a new implementation as an answer. Could you please look at it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a:

```
if (s5 % 100 == 0)
  cout << s1 << ' ' << s2 << ' ' << s3 << ' ' << s4 << ' ' << s5
       << '\r' << std::flush;
```

just below

```
for (int s5 = s4 + 24 + 24 - 1; s5 <= 480 - 24 + 1; s5++)
{
```

you'll get an idea of the speed of your algorithm (and you'll immediately see that it'll "never" end).

I haven't studied your problem in depth so I won't try a different approach. Keeping your algorithm, there are some things you have to fix:

- you should check (and somewhere reset) the `index` variable: it's growing bigger and bigger and you'll get a segmentation fault (`A[indices1[ind1]][index]`).
- the `indices1`, ... `indices5` vectors will rapidly become very large and the `std::sort` function will take a lot of time.

  It seems to me that you aren't using all the element in the vector, e.g.:

  ```
  std::sort(indices1.begin(), indices1.end());

  N = 11 * 10;
  for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < N; ++ind1)
    A [indices1[ind1]][index] = 1;
  ```

  If you just need the first `N` elements you could use `std::partial_sort`:

  ```
  N = 11 * 10;
  std::partial_sort(indices1.begin(), indices1.begin() + N, indices1.end());
  ```

  this will be way faster (but probably not fast enough).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'm afraid it will be to slow yet still, but thanks for your comments :)!

Comment: Btw, N is actually the total number of elements in the vector, so I think I'd still need to sort everything.

Comment: @dreamer `N` should be the number of elements in the `indices1` vector at the "first round" of `push_back`s (10 `push_back` for 11 iterations of the `for` loop). But the program is going to execute the `for` loop a lot of time without resetting the `indices1` vector (same for the other `indices` vectors). To be honest I haven't understood the logic of the program but probably duplicates could be removed and a better container for `indices1`, ... `indices5` is `std::set` (no duplicates and always sorted).